# zsh - print array duplicates ONLY

Tags: arrays, duplicates, zsh

Not trying to blindly remove duplicates from an array.

**I want to print out any duplicate values a given array might have.**

When I use this command:

```
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}" | awk '!($0 in seen){seen[$0];print $0}'
```

...it prints out all unique values, and leaves the duplicates out.

Expected this to do the opposite, but get no results:

```
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}" | awk '($0 in seen){seen[$0];print $0}'
```

Sample Input:

```
arr=(1 2 2 3)
```

Expected Output:

```
2
```

**EDIT**

Right now, this seems to be working. Leaving it open for a day or so in case someone has a better way...

```
array=($arr)
for value in ${array[@]}; do
    [[ $(grep "${value}" $(echo ${(F)arr} | wc -l) -gt 1 ]] && echo $value;
done
```

Comment: `print -l $arr|sort|uniq -d` is the way I'd usually do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very short: just print the value when the count is *exactly* 1 (which occurs on the first duplicate you see):

```
% print -l $arr | awk 'a[$0]++ == 1'
```

You can do something similar in pure `zsh`:

```
% () { local -A a; for x; do ((a[$x]++ == 1)) && print $x; done } $arr
2
```

The anonymous function is simply used to localize the use of the array `a`. An associative array is used to accommodate arrays of any values, not just integer values.

Slightly shorter, using an short form of `for`:

```
% () { local -A a; for x; { ((a[$x]++ == 1)) && print $x } } $arr
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I didn't know about that actionless `awk` syntax - this is much more elegant than my solution!

Comment: Right, without an explicit action, `{ print }` is assumed.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there:

```
printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}" | awk '{ if (count[$0] > 0) print $0; else count[$0]++ }'
```

The first time a value is seen, the array index is incremented to 1. Any time the value is seen again, the value is just printed. If you only want the duplicates printed once, you could do it another way:

```
printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}" | awk '{ count[$0]++ } END { for (i in count) { if (count[i] > 1) print i } }'
```

In this version, each value is used as an index and the count is incremented. At the end, we loop through the array and print any index that has a count greater than 1. You could also take the first version and simply pipe to `uniq`.

Answer (score 1):

Here a pure zsh solution, without reverting to external program:

```
arr=(1 2 2 3)
duparr=()  # This will be the resulting array of duplicate values
typeset -U duparr
for s in "${arr[@]}"
do
  if [[ ${arr[(ie)$s]} != ${arr[(Ie)$s]} ]]
  then
    duparr+=($s)
  fi
done
echo $duparr
```

The trick here is to use the array index modifier flags `(ie)` and `(Ie)`. `${arr[(ie)$s]}` returns the index of the first occurance of `$s` in `$arr` and `${arr[(Ie)$s]}` returns the last one. If an element is a duplicate, these index expressions will differ and we collect them into `duparr`.

But since we loop over the whole `arr`, `duparr` will now contain each duplicate value at least twice. `typeset -U duparr` ensures that only one occurance is stored.

**UPDATE** : Changed the flags from `(i)` (i.e. find with pattern matching) to `(ie)` (i.e. find literally). While the difference does not matter for the concrete data in the question, it might for the general case (when the strings in `arr` contain wildcard characters).